# Right angle brackets cause my php tag in html to end prematurely

Tags: php, html, windows

If I try something as simple as:

```
    <?php echo "<li>test</li>"; ?>
```

The first > ends my php tag, showing the result on my html as such:

```
test"; ?>
```

Every example I've seen claims this should work as intended, but it just doesn't. Am I missing something here?

Using wamp. This bit of code is in a html file that I've opened though localhost/
Other php code (from a .php file) does run, provided I don't use > in it.
If I use echo in the html page without > in it, it doesn't print anything.

After a trying a bit more, it seems I also can't get anything echoed or printed onto the html page from php. I can only get stuff printed when on the php page. I'm not certain if the two problems are related.

Comment: are your file extension is .php? and php enabled on that server?

Comment: what is the source of html?

Comment: can you show what exactly you are doing ?

Comment: If your server isn't parsing the PHP

Comment: try <?php echo "hello world"; ?> ... does that work?

Comment: well, if server was not parsing PHP then it should output : `<?php echo "<li>test</li>"; ?>`

Comment: @AspiringAqib But the browser will parse the `<?php` tags and only display half of it...!

Comment: If I don't add any >; then it doesn't parse anything, even if I use echo. Weird. I'm running this on my local machine and php does run. I know it's running because I do print some stuff from seperate php file. I can't use > in that file either. This bit of code is inserted in a html file: <!DOCTYPE html> The html file's other stuff works normally.

Comment: what are you using wamp lamp or mamp..??

Comment: are you opening file in the browser by double clicking on it, or you are opening it by going to localhost/myfile.php? what is the url in the browser when you open it?

Comment: I'm using wamp and have the page opened via http://localhost/hf/contact.html the page uses form action="contactformulier.php" method="POST" at some point and I know it runs the php code from that file just fine, as long as I don't use > in it. I'll update my first post a bit.

Comment: @AspiringAqib - it won't show that in the browser view, since the browser tries to render the angle brackets and their contents as HTML. You need to view source to see the whole string.

Comment: "closed as too localized...This question is unlikely to help any future visitors..." It helped me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server doesn't process html files as php. You can either add php handler to your apache configuration for html files by adding `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` in `mime_module`, and restart apache, or you can rename your html file to php, which is better imho.

Comment: Read his comments, his php file is called "contactformulier.php"

Comment: I did. He opens `localhost/hf/contact.html` which doesn't work, check comments in his first post

Comment: This is it. Thank you! To clarify: I had a contact.html which used contactformulier.php to process a form. I didn't realize the server code by default ignores php code outside php files.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the PHP preprocessor isnt working or isnt installed on your machine. Can you test the php install by creating and running the following script:

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: If I add  phpinfo(); to a seperate file (test.php) it works: I get whole lists. If I put it into my html page, I get nothing. (though I'm probably not supposed to get anything then)

Comment: Yes your php files need to be named with a .php extension, not a .html